# Is there a same way as the axios interceptor when I use fetch?

Tags: axios, fetch-api, interceptor

I am working on the nextjs project and here I used the original fetch method for API request.
But here I have to add token every time so I tried to find the same way as the axios interceptors and didn't find yet. Can anybody help me, please?